# Delayed RESET to MCU pin

Tags: solar-cell, leakage-current

Using the following schematic, I am charging a supercap (3.3F, 3V) via a solar panel and would like to keep a downstream microcontroller in reset mode until the supercap has charged a bit.

To do so, I am charging a separate 100uF capacitor via a 1MOhm resistor (according to [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/capacitor-Charge-and-time-constant-calculator/), it would take 100 seconds for 1 tau).

I am worried about the leakage current (according to [this](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/40/TPS_AUTO-845414.pdf), it's about 6.3uA).
Does this mean that the 1MOhm resistor is too big and the charging current would just get leaked away (3V /1000000Ohm = 3uA current < 6.3uA leakage)?

Circuit:
[image: circuit]

Comment: Why don't you use a comparator that keeps the MCU in reset until the voltage on the supercap reaches a certain value?

Comment: Just as an aside, shouldn't you put some over voltage protection on that circuit? It seems that you may exceed the working voltage on your super cap on bright sunny days. What is the brownout voltage on the MCU?

Comment: @ScienceGeyser The voltage output of a PV panel is effectively not related to the intensity of the incoming sunlight. In other words, Voc is a constant.

Comment: Which MCU? Many have built-in voltage monitors.

Comment: @jwh20 As the capacitor charges, the voltage rises. If you continue to charge the cap you will eventually exceed the working voltage. The given rating of the solar cell says nothing of the area which will determine the current given to the cap.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts everyone. Here are my answers:

Andyaka, yes - that can be done. However it consumes >20uA and I only need it when the Supercap charges.

ScienceGeyser: yes, I use a led with 2.9V activation voltage. I've done the math and tested on a breadbord. The led in the schematic sinks all the provided current @ 3V.

Justme: AtMega4804. I've looked at the BOD but could do without consuming current for that block if possible.

Comment: @MihaiGalos an appropriate op-amp and shunt reference can consume about 1 microamp.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser  That is true but it has nothing to do with the intensity of the incoming light. The cap's working voltage of 3.3V may be exceeded if you power the PV with a flashlight.

Comment: What is the power rating of 4V PV? 200mW? and uC type?

Comment: Yes the leakage @ 100uF represents a 1MOhm voltage divide /2  Consider 33uF, Vih min when uC goes out of reset threshold at low voltage and stays operational. Pd charge rate.  then uC load and Solar Input to prevent BO oscillation

Comment: @MihaiGalos 5 mA is the maximum current from the solar cell? The LED will be at 20 mA when the voltage is 3.3. 20 mA still seems low unless the solar cell is very small. Could you give some additional specs on the solar cell? I know all of this is not answering your question and I apologize for that... But, this does get to the point of why you would need the delay and how long the delay might need to be to insure the proper operation of the device during dark hours.

Comment: Tony: it's 26.3mW (5.9mA, 4.46V) https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/en/anysolar-ltd/KXOB25-02X8F-TR/KXOB25-02X8FCT-ND/9990480. MCU: Atmega4808.

ScienceGeyser: yes, about 5mA. The solar cell is very small  (23.00mm x 8.00mm x 1.80mm) but efficient (25% at wafer level).
Sure, no problem. I think the process of coming to a solution is probably just as important. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: The choice of UltraCap and Reset cap are critical. 100uF is too big.. What boot time and brownout time do you need? This depends on load current and Solarity if you want it to run all day or night without brownout. Which supercap? 100uF is too big for this series R of 1M

Comment: Tony: 3.3F @ 3V Supercap from Vinatech (https://www.conrad.de/de/p/vinatech-vec3r0335qg-doppelschicht-kondensator-3-3-f-3-v-x-l-8-mm-x-20-mm-1-st-1529294.html). It only needs to run during daytime, no night.
Yes, I was suspecting the 100uF was too big for 1M.

Comment: What is Ambient temp?  Vmax / Vrated both affect MTBF greatly. Also uAh charge avail (solarity) and uAh load

Comment: That cap has a leakage rating of CV = 10uA which at 3V is 330k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary concerns for this design are the choice of both Caps and how that affects Boot reset time, Brownout time (BO) with solar input and load current and thus stability of reset threshold and mAh of capacity with a leaky ultracap. It is unknown if the application is intended to run overnight and what the brownout duration of solar input is expected.

The leakage resistance of the tantalum cap of 100uF 4V = 1MOhm thus the voltage may be attenuated with series R of 1M by up to 50%.  Although the POR threshold is programmable, the leakage R has a variable tolerance. The POR has a filter but unknown if it has hysteresis, so noise might be amplified at the threshold so **this cap choice would be poor due to leakage and Rs=1M**. **A much smaller cap will have a lower leakage current that ought to be used.**

Since the supercap charge time constant is much greater than the RESET time constant of 100s, **it becomes irrelevant for time delay**. You could use 1ms instead

Thus only the threshold for detecting RESET ON and OFF and hysteresis are relevant.  Consider 1.75 to 2V

---

Other comments.

The size of the Supercap depends on the ratio of min uAh charge available and uAh load expected without brownout duration based on historical residual charge voltage and regional solarity.
The power consumption for low f clock rates may be considered low (1mA) if peripherals are managed so a large Reset capacitor is not necessary with a 100s LPF and ripple reduction from a DC source.  Consider dV/dt = Ic/C for both charge time and leakage decay time affects both time to Boot ( Clear reset) and Brownout time (decay to Reset)

The supercap may have a high ESR (100 Ohms)  It may also have a low voltage rating.

Consider both the mAh of charge time needed to boot and mAh discharge time of the application before brownout and the ESR of the supercap for stable reset threshold detection.

### Hypothetical analysis

- Consider uC low voltage threshold of 1.75V and use 2V for some margin before reset is removed.
- Consider sunrise current of 10% of rated or 590 uA and a 15 minute boot time from 0V which is ~ 150 uAh charge rate.
- Consider a total daily charge capacity of 8h at 25% or 5.9mA/4 * 8h = 11.8 mAh
- what capacity is available from 3V to 2V for a 16h dark time from 2.9V (LED Vf) to 1.75V the uC Vdd min rating?
- 11.8mAh /16h = 737 uA average
- 25% might be too much if cloudy days are expected to sustain the operation.
- what is the maximum and average climate temperature> This will reduce a 10yr lifespan by 50% for every 10'C rise above 25'C.

C= Ic * dt/dV = 590 uA * 15 * 60s /2V = 0.265 F

Choose 300 mF, for longer backup time or uAh, consider 1F.

- only consider those with known leakage current ratings if holdup time is critical which also depends on temp.

Comment: Follow-up question: your dV is 2V in your calculation. I always assumed that it's the difference in voltage from when the circuit correctly functions (i.e.: supercap fully charged) up to the point where it stops functioning (i.e.: 2V). In that case 3V-2V=1V, correct? If yes, that would double your computed C to 0.53F.

Comment: 2V for initial charge then 1V for subsequent discharge if using continuously

Comment: I might consider 1F 5V 0.2 Ohms ESR  leakage rate ? <$5 https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/avx-corporation/SCMR18C105PRBA0/6166286  longer 1st time use but greater storage capacity